# Como fazer com que "Replace" substitua todas as ocorrências de uma palavra sem ter em conta maiúsculas ou minúsculas?

Tags: c#, .net, string, regex, case-insensitive

A função `Replace` substitui todas as ocorrências de uma palavra ou expressão, mas tendo em conta maiúsculas e minúsculas:

```
string str = "Hello WorLLd";//Substitui só os 'l' e não o 'L'
str = str.Replace("l", "EL");
Console.WriteLine("My string: " + str);
```

Output:

```
My string: HeELELo WorLLd
```

Gostaria que o output fosse:

```
My string: HeELELo WorELELd
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode usar o [`Regex.Replace()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Replace_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_Text_RegularExpressions_RegexOptions_). Algo assim:

```
string str = "Hello WorLLd"; //Substitui só os 'l' e não o 'L'
str = Regex.Replace(str, "l", "EL", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Console.WriteLine("My string: " + str);
```

Para quem não gosta de `Regex`, achei essa solução em uma [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/244933/221800):

```
public static string ReplaceString(string str, string oldValue, string newValue, StringComparison comparison = StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int previousIndex = 0;
    int index = str.IndexOf(oldValue, comparison);
    while (index != -1) {
        sb.Append(str.Substring(previousIndex, index - previousIndex));
        sb.Append(newValue);
        index += oldValue.Length;
        previousIndex = index;
        index = str.IndexOf(oldValue, index, comparison);
    }
    sb.Append(str.Substring(previousIndex));
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/ReplaceAllInsensitive.cs).

O segredo é a enumeração [`StringComparison`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparison?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0) no [`IndexOf()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0#System_String_IndexOf_System_String_System_Int32_System_StringComparison_). Uso:

```
ReplaceString("Hello WorLLd", "l", "EL")
```

Tem uma outra [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6755752/221800) que é um pouco melhor por já ser um método de extensão para `string` e evitar um [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-6.0). Mas a construção do `while`com `break` é desnecessária. O ideal seria melhorar isto, mas ainda me parece uma solução melhor assim mesmo.

```
public static class StringExtensions {
    public static string Replace(this string originalString, string oldValue, string newValue, StringComparison comparisonType) {
        int startIndex = 0;
        while (true) {
            startIndex = originalString.IndexOf(oldValue, startIndex, comparisonType);
            if (startIndex == -1)
                break;
            originalString = originalString.Substring(0, startIndex) + newValue + originalString.Substring(startIndex + oldValue.Length);
            startIndex += newValue.Length;
        }
        return originalString;
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/ReplaceAllInsensitive2.cs).

Comment: @cell para coisas simples o `RegEx` é bem simples. Ele complica um pouco para casamento padrões mais sofisticados. Embora não seja bicho de sete cabeças também. Em casos onde a performance é importante o `Regex` **pode** se tornar um fardo.

Answer (score 2):

Use assim:

```
str = Regex.Replace(str, "l", "EL", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```