# Para que usar métodos de extensão do C#?

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, herança, extension-method

O que eu ganho com métodos de extensão que eu não ganho com herança?

Simplesmente usar como se tivesse o mesmo nome é complicado, uma vez que isso gera mais confusão que qualquer outra coisa.

Comment: Explique melhor a segunda frase.

Comment: Tipo eu uso String um milhão de vezes e conheço tudo sobre ela, mas dai ela tem algum método diferente do esperado...

Comment: Eiu explico isto na minha resposta, mas vou melhorar sobre este ponto.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Tem uma pergunta que responde em parte o que está sendo perguntado aqui: [Java 8 "default method" versus C# "extend method"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/121240/101). Não vou repetir aqui o que já está lá.

Método de extensão nada tem a ver com herança. Na verdade o [uso de herança é abusado e deve ser evitado sempre que possível](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11378/101).

Métodos de extensão não adicionam comportamento para uma classe. Eles são métodos utilitários sem relação, que trabalham primariamente com um tipo de dado. Ele é só um açúcar sintático em métodos estáticos fora de classes e não há uma relação de herança. Portanto possuem desvantagens citadas na pergunta *linkada* acima.

Todas as linguagens modernas estão provendo mecanismos de extensibilidade melhores que a herança depois de perceberem que esta última não entrega as maravilhas que pregavam no começo. A herança ainda é útil onde o polimorfismo é necessário e o reuso também.

- Ganha uma sintaxe mais fluente que métodos estáticos, o que inclusive ajuda o IDE te ajudar.
- Ganha a redução do acoplamento de funcionalidades. Ele reduz a necessidade de usar padrões de projeto para obter esse tipo de vantagem (ok, isso pode ser obtido só com métodos estáticos, mas assim é mais conveniente). [Herança é um dos piores tipos de acoplamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101).
- Ganha a possibilidade de adicionar funcionalidades justamente sem fazer herança. Vários tipos sequer podem ser herdados (`structs`, classes `sealed`, `record` e `enum` - [exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/123841/101)). A herança seria inadequada em outros. Então ele é usado mais para adicionar funcionalidades em algo que já existe e você não possui ou não quer ter controle.
- Permite vincular métodos à interfaces. Isso é muito poderoso, principalmente se considerar que costuma ser melhor [programar para interfaces](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86484/101). Aumenta o reuso (desde a versão 8 tem maneiras até mais interessantes).
- Deixa escolher (dependendo de como ele foi escrito) no momento do uso se ele estará disponível para seu código ou não. Por exemplo, se não adiciona o `System.Linq` no seu código, os métodos do LINQ não poluem as possibilidades de uso de métodos.
- Ele é a base do [LINQ](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125601/101). Sem métodos de extensão seria extremamente complexo e haveria muita incompatibilidade criá-lo (veja Java). Isso é um enorme ganho.

## Confusão de nomes de métodos extras

Uma das coisas que orienta-se evitar é não colocar a classe estática do(s) método(s) de extensão no mesmo [*namespace*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11199/101) que o tipo que ele está estendendo. Isso fará com que o método de extensão fique sempre disponível para aquele tipo. Claro que até pode ser útil e fazer isso, mas só faça se estiver certo que será vantajoso.

Se só quer que o método de extensão esteja disponível quando escolher, basta criar em um *namespace* separado e aí somente com sua importação (com `using`) que o método estará disponível.

Por exemplo evite criar um:

```
namespace System {
    public static class ObjectExt {
        pubic static bool IsNull(this object source) => source == null;
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/ExtensionSystem.cs).

Isso fará que todos objetos de todos os tipos tenham esse método disponível, sempre!

Todo recurso pode ser abusado. Não abuse deste.

Se pegar algo que abusou e te atrapalha, considere trocar de "fornecedor".

## Conclusão

Lembrando que o acesso ao objeto em um método de extensão não tem privilégios de acesso aos membro não públicos. O que pode ser até uma boa na maioria dos casos. Mas pode trazer alguma dificuldade em outras.

Há controvérsias se a herança ou métodos de extensão devem ser usados como padrão quando é possível ambos.

## Exemplos do uso:

#### Usando interface:

```
static Random r = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list, int lowerItem, int upperItem) {
    upperItem = upperItem > list.Count ? list.Count : upperItem;
    lowerItem = lowerItem < 0 ? 0 : lowerItem;
    for (int i = lowerItem; i < upperItem; i++) {
        int j = r.Next(i, upperItem);
        T tmp = list[j];
        list[j] = list[i];
        list[i] = tmp;
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/Extension.cs).

- [Filtrar itens que não contenha palavra em meu list](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128150/101)
- [Como fazer com que "Replace" substitua todas as ocorrências de uma palavra sem ter em conta maiúsculas ou minúsculas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32245/101)
- [Remover caracteres especiais e espaços de uma string?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/98332/101)
- [Remover elemento do de um vetor em C# e não deixar o vetor com um espaço em branco?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/117570/101)
- [Como alinhar uma string em um espaço de 42 caracteres](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/41755/101)

[Site com vários métodos úteis](http://www.extensionmethod.net/), alguns abusados.

Comment: Só não entendi o (açúcar sintático), mas a parte do LINQ deixa ele bem quetinho que esta muito bem usando da forma que é.

Comment: Já achei a [Aqui](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%C3%A7%C3%BAcar_sint%C3%A1tico)

Comment: De fato vi alguma vantagem agora, algumas vantagens parecem as mesmas de composição sobre herança...   Uma coisa que li ali e que me deixou curioso "Ganha a possibilidade de vincular métodos à interfaces" Isso é verdade? Tipo uma interface com a implementação de um método? Desculpa ai eu usava Java e algumas coisas ainda são estranhas no C#

Comment: @diegocolli sim, é verdade, mas não é tão bom quanto o que dá para fazer em Java. leia o primeiro *link* sobre as diferenças entre as linguagens neste ponto. Pelo menos hoje. As linguagens evoluem. Java não tinha nada, o C# planeja um recurso mais poderoso ainda.

Comment: O que você acha da ideia de simular "mixins" com Extensions Methods, @bigown? Eu li um artigo antigo sobre essa ideia, que eu não consigo encontrar, mas achei a ideia interessante. Claro, o uso da palavra "mixin" não é a mais adequada, mas a ideia em si eu achei boa.

Comment: Para explicar melhor, um post de exemplo, que não é muito bom, mas serve para exemplificar: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27930/Understanding-Extension-Methods-and-Mixin

E esse gist que eu montei baseado na ideia.
https://gist.github.com/gtkatakura/60c8de78274588a049cabc66a6ffb16b

Comment: Apesar de não ser a ideia de um "Mixin", já que não temos linearização aqui e [talvez?] não temos até mesmo um "estado", a ideia parece mais com uma "Trait". Só que não temos uma resolução explícita de conflitos, então também não cai no conceito de "Traits".

Comment: @GabrielKatakura ou seja, não é nem *mixin*, nem *trait*. Há uma proposta para se adicionar *trait* no C#, mas só vão fazer quando tiverem certeza que vão fazer direito.

Comment: O exemplo utilizado para `ObjectExt ` não daria certo pois se o objeto for nulo resultaria em um `NullReferenceException`. Mas no geral gostei da resposta.

Comment: Sim, na verdade a ideia está longe de ser um Mixin, ela é mais próxima de uma Trait. Na minha opinião, parece algo mais próximo ainda dos Defaults Methods de Java.

Comment: @RichardDias você está enganado, não está acessando nenhum membro, então não geraria erro.

Comment: @GabrielKatakura mas também não é, veja o primeiro *link* da resposta.

Comment: @bigown, imaginando a utilização da seguinte forma: `var obj = PegarPorId('IDInexistenteParaRetornarNull');  obj.IsNull(); //Null reference exception`. Não seria assim?

Comment: Não, porque é açúcar sintático para `System.ObjectExt.IsNull(obj)` :) O método não faz parte do objeto de verdade, o objeto não precisa existir para invocar o método de extensão.

Answer (score 13):

Os métodos de extensão permite você adicionar um método a uma classe sem criar um novo tipo derivado, algumas classes não podem ser herdadas como a classe String e os tipos valores (Structs).

Você pode querer por exemplo contar quantas palavras tem em uma string e para isso

```
namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static int WordCount(this String str)
        {
            return str.Split(new char[] { ' ', '.', '?' }, 
                             StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
        }
    }   
}
```

e para usar

```
using ExtensionMethods;

string s = "Hello Extension Methods";
int i = s.WordCount();             // com extension
int j = MyExtensions.WordCount(s); // sem extension
```

Comment: Ok não sabia que não podia herdar de algumas classes no C#

Comment: @diegocolli As classes "marcadas" com o modificador [sealed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw.aspx) não podem ser herdadas. Veja [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx) como a classe String é declarada.

Answer (score 5):

Um ponto que não vi ninguém abordar, e um pouco mais técnico, é um tipo de code-bloating que consome mais memória do que o desejável.

Quanto mais uma classe possui membros definidos maior é a quantidade de metadados armazenados na memória que são necessários para representar a existência do tipo. Esses metadados são necessários independentemente de se usar reflexão ou não, pelo menos em parte, por causa do Garbage Collector. Este por sua vez, usa as informações de tipos dos objetos para poder navegar no grafo de objetos e poder limpar aqueles que não são referenciados por nenhum outro objeto, então ele precisa saber o layout de memória de cada tipo.

Aumentar a quantidade de metadados não é necessariamente ruim, mas um problema surge na utilização de generics. Um tipo genérico como `List<T>` que ao longo dos anos veio ganhando cada vez mais membros, é que sempre que um novo tipo `List<T1>`... `List<Tn>` é definido, uma nova porção de memória é alocada para armazenar os metadados daquele tipo, pois cada instância de objeto aponta para o seu metadado. Cada vez que o tipo genérico aumenta, esse aumento é multiplicado por todas as diferentes utilizações específicas do tipo genérico, e assim sendo se começa a usar muita memória só com metadados.

Os extension methods vieram em boa hora para acabar com a necessidade de expandir esses tipos, de forma que todos eles se mantiverem bem estáveis desde que esse recurso foi introduzido.

Answer (score 3):

Vamos a algo bem prático, para um entendimento sem complicação!

Você tem que fazer determinada operação em um tipo de objeto várias vezes, por exemplo, limpar uma string e deixar somente os números, certo!

Ao invés de construir uma classe com um método, e chamar esta para o objeto que precisa do tratamento, cria-se uma extensão deste tipo, o qual ficará disponível neste objeto sempre em todo o teu sistema!

```
public static string OnlyNumbers(this string str)
{
    List<char> numbers = new List<char>("0123456789");
    StringBuilder toReturn = new StringBuilder(str.Length);
    CharEnumerator enumerator = str.GetEnumerator();

    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        if (numbers.Contains(enumerator.Current))
            toReturn.Append(enumerator.Current);
    }
    return toReturn.ToString();
}
```

Neste caso retornamos o novo valor desta string onde só tem números!

O negócio é, determinada ação é feita repetidamente para um tipo de objeto, então é mais prático criar um método estendido daquele tipo!

**Aplicação**

```
string telefone = telefonePosted.OnlyNumbers();
```

Comment: Só complementado, **qual ficará disponível neste objeto sempre em todo o teu sistema!** .... isso somente onde a classe referenciar a classe que contem o método.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza para ficar disponível em todo o teu sistema, basta usar  o mesmo Namespace para a classe/método de extensão que a classe base! ;) (Claro que em todos o teu sistema, uma vez que referencies o tipo base, a extensão estará disponível)