# MVC Helper com List generica

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, genéricos

Estou criando um Helper em meu projeto Asp.Net MVC 5, e gostaria de receber como parâmetro uma lista genérica, mas o seguinte trecho de código não funciona:

```
@helper MeuHelper(string param1, int param2, List<T> param3)
{
   // Sequência de código
}
```

O erro gerado é:

> The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)

Afinal, é possível fazer com que meu helper receba no `param3` uma lista genérica?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Não** é possível diretamente fazer com que o [`@helper`](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor) tenha paramentos genéricos (*pelo menos até o momento*), claro existe outros meios que talvez não condiz com aquilo que precisa mas, um exemplo de como poderia trabalhar com a ***informação***:

```
@helper MeuHelper(string param1, int param2, System.Collections.IEnumerable param3)
{
    <div>@(param1)</div>
    <div>@(param2)</div>
    var items = param3.GetEnumerator();
    while (items.MoveNext())
    {
            <div>@(items.Current)</div>
    }
}


@functions
{
    public HelperResult MeuHelperFunction<T>(string param1, int param2, List<T> param3)
    {
        return MeuHelper(param1, param2, param3);
    }
}


@MeuHelperFunction("Nome", 1, new int[] { 1, 2, 2, 4, 5 }.ToList())
```

o [`@helper`](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor) é chamado por uma função (`@MeuHelperFunction`) que tem um parâmetro `IEnumerable` que vai aceitar essa lista de qualquer tipo, é uma forma razoável. Reforçando o [`@helper`](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor) não aceita paramentos genéricos é para codificação pontual e simples.

---

A forma melhor de trabalhar com isso é fazer um [***método de extensão***](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/136913/para-que-usar-m%C3%A9todos-de-extens%C3%A3o-do-c) que aceita tranquilamente **parâmetros genéricos**, exemplo:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public static class MyHelperExtension
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString MeuHelper<T>(this HtmlHelper _html,
                                                 string param1, 
                                                 int param2, 
                                                 List<T> param3)
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Chamando na `View`:

```
@Html.MeuHelper("Nome", 1, new int[] { 1, 2, 2, 4, 5 }.ToList())
```

---

Na versão `Core` (`MVC6`) por exemplo, [foi removido](http://Removed%20@helper%20directive) [@helper](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor) e foi introduzido [TagHelpers](https://dannyvanderkraan.wordpress.com/2016/04/19/asp-net-core-1-0-goodbye-html-helpers-and-hello-taghelpers/).

***Referencias:***

- [Simple @helper method scenario](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor)
- [Creating and Using a Helper in an ASP.NET Web Pages (Razor) Site](https://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/ui-layouts-and-themes/creating-and-using-a-helper-in-an-aspnet-web-pages-site)
- [Comparing MVC 3 Helpers: Using Extension Methods and Declarative Razor @helper Syntax](https://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/comparing-mvc-3-helpers-using-extension-methods-and-declarative-razor-helper)
- [Is it possible to create a generic @helper method with Razor?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4760872/6797930)
- [Para que usar métodos de extensão do C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/136913/para-que-usar-m%C3%A9todos-de-extens%C3%A3o-do-c)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta! Na verdade funcionou aqui a primeira proposta só com o `IEnumerable` no lugar do meu `List<T>`. Não precisou nem criar nada em `functions`.