# O que são funções estendidas?

Tags: android, funções, terminologia, característica-linguagem, kotlin

Estou escrevendo um artigo sobre programação em Kotlin, me deparei com esse nome, o que são funções estendidas?

Comment: Por curiosidade, que tipo de artigo você está escrevendo?

Comment: É um artigo científico pra uma matéria da faculdade, ele não é muito elaborado, é de até 4 páginas

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Imagino que esteja falando de [Extension Functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) ou funções de extensão.

Elas são usadas para estender funcionalidades em um tipo existente.

Você as escreve como funções normais e ela funciona como se fosse uma função do tipo, ou seja, como se fosse um método que aquele tipo possui.

O `this` pode ser usado como em um método normal para acessar o objeto que está sendo manipulado. Mas há limitações do que pode acessar nele. Apenas membros públicos podem ser acessados já que a função é externa e não tem privilégios de acesso extras.

Conforme a documentação se quiser fazer um método que possa ser usado em qualquer `MutableList` de um `Int` que troque dados de dois índices faria assim:

```
fun MutableList<Int>.swap(index1: Int, index2: Int) {
    val tmp = this[index1] // 'this' corresponds to the list
    this[index1] = this[index2]
    this[index2] = tmp
}
```

Assim poderia ser usado desta forma:

```
val l = mutableListOf(1, 2, 3)
l.swap(0, 2)
```

Se Kotlin tivesse métodos estáticos normais (ela tem objetos de companhia que é essencialmente a mesma coisa) seria o mesmo que chamar

```
MutableList<Int>.swap(l, 0, 2)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Kotlin/ExtendedFunctions.kt).

neste caso o `l` seria passado como argumento para a função e este parâmetro seria acessado com `this`.

[C# já tinha algo parecido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136913/101).

Comment: Quando vc faz MutableList<Int>.swap(l, 0, 2) , vc está passando 3 parametros sendo que na declaração da função swap espera-se 2 (index1,index2) . Como que ele sabe que o primeiro parametro é a lista sobre a qual eu vou fazer a operação?

Comment: @L.J eu não falei que funciona, falei que é o mesmo que se fizesse isto em um método estático normal (bom Kotlin não usa essa terminologia).

Comment: Ah sim, tinha entendido que isso  funcionaria: MutableList<Int>.swap(l, 0, 2) Ainda bem que perguntei...rsrs. Quando você diz :(bom Kotlin não usa essa terminologia) está dizendo que Kotlin não tem métodos estáticos ou possui com outra terminologia?

Comment: @L.J só outra terminologia, mas é a mesma coisa, a extensão tb é um método estático com sintaxe diferente.