# Qual é a maneira de se truncar uma string em Csharp?

Tags: c#, string

Tenho um cenário onde eu tenho definido o tamanho máximo de um campo. Eu quero cortar esse valor até o limite. Estou fazendo isso através do `Substring`, porém retorna um erro quando eu tenho um caractere de tamanho menor.

Exemplo:

```
int limite = 20;

string texto1 = "meu nome é wallace de souza";      
string texto2 = "meu nome é wallace";

Console.WriteLine(texto1.Substring(0, limite));
// 'meu nome é wallace d'

Console.WriteLine(texto2.Substring(0, limite));
//Erro: ArgumentOutOfRangeException
```

O erro gerado é:

> [System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
>   Parameter name: length]

Em imaginei que o C# fosse ignorar o tamanho da string na hora de cortá-la com `Substring`, porém não foi bem como eu pensava.

Existe algum método simples em C# para truncar uma string para um determinado tamanho?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basta verificar se o tamanho da string é `menor/igual` ao limite, use um `if` ternário.

```
texto1.Length <= limite ?  texto1 :  texto1.Substring(0, limite);
```

Outro jeito é usando *[Math.Min Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.min(v=vs.110).aspx)*, que retorna o menor de dois inteiros assinados, evitando ultrapassar o tamanho da sua string.

```
texto1.Substring(0, Math.Min(texto1.Length, limite));
```

## [Extensions](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/136913/para-que-usar-m%C3%A9todos-de-extens%C3%A3o-do-c):

```
public static class StringExt
{
    public static string Truncate(this string value, int maxLength)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) return value;
        return value.Length <= maxLength ? value : value.Substring(0, maxLength); 
    }
}
```

O bom de você adicionar um método de extensão é que você pode usá-lo em qualquer `string`:

```
 texto1.Truncate(limite);
```

<sup>**[How do I truncate a .NET string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776673/how-do-i-truncate-a-net-string)**</sup>

Comment: Boa. Eu vi uma resposta em algum lugar que ensinava usar o `Math.Min`

Comment: @WallaceMaxters sim,  o `Math.Min` vai retornar o menor de seus dois argumentos, ou seja, se sua string for menor que o limite ele irá retorna ela.

Comment: Seu código tá bem parecido com [este](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2776689/4190610)

Comment: @LINQ fonte adicionada.

Answer (score 5):

Por que não criar um método de extensão e ser feliz pra sempre? Você pode ler sobre eles em [Para que usar métodos de extensão do C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136913/18246)

```
public static class StringUtilsExtensions
{
    public static string Trunc(this string original, int length)
    {
        return original?.Substring(0, Math.Min(original.Length, length)) ?? "";
    }
}
```

Código executável

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string texto1 = "meu nome é wallace de souza";          
        Console.WriteLine(texto1.Trunc(20));
    }
}

public static class StringUtilsExtensions
{
    public static string Trunc(this string original, int length)
    {
        return original?.Substring(0, Math.Min(original.Length, length)) ?? "";
    }
}
```

<sup>[**Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle.**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/B4QTri)</sup>