# Como tratar de forma especifica um KeyNotFoundException?

Tags: c#

Estou com uma duvida, tentei encontrar algum conteúdo no Google mas não encontrei.

Tenho um bloco `try catch` da seguinte maneira:

```
try
{
    //código
    string idFormaPgto = Dictionaries.FormaPgto[_order.FK_PEDIDOS_FORMA_PAGAMENTO];
    //restante do código
}
catch(Exception e)
{

}
```

O problema é que algumas vezes vou receber um `KeyNotFoundException` porém o código seguinte **DEVE** continuar e eu preciso setar um vallor padrão para `idFormaPgto`, não sei se existe uma forma mais elegante e correta de tratar isso, o que eu pensei foi:

```
try
{
    //código
    string idFormaPgto = "";
    try
    {
       idFormaPgto = Dictionaries.FormaPgto[_order.FK_PEDIDOS_FORMA_PAGAMENTO];
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
       idFormaPgto = "1"; //tratamento do idFormaPgto 
    }
    //restante do código
}
catch(Exception e)
{

}
```

O meu código soluciona o problema, porém acredito que não seja a maneira mais correta de se fazer isso, talvez utilizando algum método de extensão da classe [`Dictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) mas não conheço nenhum. O objetivo é, tratar esse `KeyNotFoundException` sem usar `try catch` dentro de `try catch`

Comment: Mas o outro catch vai servir pra algo?

Comment: Vai, é que assim... serão várias consultas dentro do catch principal, algumas consultas podem resultar em exception outras não, por exemplo essa chamada no dictionary **não pode** cair no catch principal, as outras sim, por isso estou tratando ela em especifica, porém acho que está "porco"

Comment: Me parece que o tratamento adequando seria você fazer o catch da exceção que você já espera... no caso o `KeyNotFoundException`

Comment: Então pq não checa se a chave existe antes de usar?

Comment: @LINQ é uma possível solução, porém não queria usar blocos, tipo try catch, if else ou o que for sabe ? Você conhece alguma função no estilo "Se não existir retorne isso" tudo em uma linha só ? como se fosse um FirstOrDefault

Comment: @LeonardoBonetti Conheço, vou tentar escrever pra você =)

Comment: @LINQ Ok, no aguardo

Comment: Vou melhorar a resposta com exemplos assim que possível. Agora preciso correr pra uma reunião.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode simplesmente usar o método **`TryGetValue`**. Este método tenta obter o valor pela chave indicada e, se a chave não existir, retorna o padrão do tipo.

```
string idFormaPgto;
Dictionaries.FormaPgto.TryGetValue[_order.FK_PEDIDOS_FORMA_PAGAMENTO, out idFormaPgto];
```

Se quiseres encurtar um pouco mais ideia e deixar mais parecido com o método `FirstOrDefault` do LINQ, é possível escrever um método de extensão para dicionários.

Por exemplo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var dicio = new Dictionary<int, string>
        {
            { 65, "A" },
            { 74, "J" },
            { 69, "E" }
        };

        Console.WriteLine(dicio.GetByKeyOrDefault(65) ?? "Chave inexistente");
        Console.WriteLine(dicio.GetByKeyOrDefault(80) ?? "Chave inexistente");
        Console.WriteLine(dicio.GetByKeyOrDefault(69) ?? "Chave inexistente");
    }
}

public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static TValue GetByKeyOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, TKey key)
        => dict.ContainsKey(key) ? dict[key] : default(TValue); 
}
```

<sup>[**Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uXQcB9)</sup>

Note que, na implementação do método, `GetByKeyOrDefault` ainda é possível fazer mais uma micro-otimização e usar o método **`TryGetValue`** para não precisar fazer duas consultas no dicionário (uma no método `ContainsKey` e outra ao obter o valor).

Comment: Eu crio uma nova classe ou insiro esse método em algum lugar?

Comment: eu confesso que não entendo como aconteceu essa extensão do método na classe `Dictionary`... como o compilador sabe que é para a classe `Dictionary` em especifico? (estou pensando em criar uma pergunta para isso)

Comment: Está atrelado ao nome da classe `DictionaryExtensions` ?

Comment: @LeonardoBonetti Pelo primeiro parâmetro. Note a keywork `this` antes dele. O que acontece é que o compilador altera a chamada para `DictionaryExtensions.GetByKeyOrDefault(dicio, 65)`. Esta é justamente uma das bases do funcionamento do LINQ.

Comment: Tem uma pergunta sobre isso https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136913/18246

Answer (score 3):

Você pode simplesmente utilizar o `Linq`, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
var dicionario= new Dictionary<string, string> {
    { "teste 1", "1" },
    { "testando", "2" },
};

var idFormaPgto = dicionario.SingleOrDefault(x=> x.Key.Equals(_order.FK_PEDIDOS_FORMA_PAGAMENTO)).Value ?? "1";
```

**Edit**
Como argumentado nos comentários essa é uma abordagem básica e só deveria ser considerada em uma aplicação pontual. É importante dar atenção às observações apontadas pelo

> **Linq:**
>   Dessa forma você perde toda a ideia de se usar um dicionário. O método
>   SingleOrDefault vai obter um enumerador, movê-lo item a item e fazer a
>   validação de cada um deles. Você simplesmente joga fora o principal
>   motivo de um dicionário que é ter complexidade de busca O(1) e passa a
>   ter complexidade de busca O(N)

Comment: Gostei dessa solução, vou testa-la

Comment: @LeonardoBonetti, Encurtei um pouco removendo o `Where` e passando o predicado direto para o `SingleOrDefault()`

Comment: Perfect ! todas as soluções foram boas, mas essa 11/10

Comment: Dessa forma você perde toda a ideia de se usar um dicionário. O método `SingleOrDefault` vai obter um enumerador, movê-lo item a item e fazer a validação de cada um deles. Você simplesmente joga fora o principal motivo de um dicionário que é ter complexidade de busca **`O(1)`** e passa a ter complexidade de busca **`O(N)`**.

Comment: @LeonardoBonetti, Exatamente como o Linq falou. A melhor abordagem é o método de extensão que o Linq apresentou, a minha resposta deveria ser considerada apenas como um contorno pontual para aquele seu trecho de código. Siga com a outra proposta, pois você estará implementando esse recurso para todos os dicionários, realmente extraindo a performance que deve ter levado a os escolher em sua estrutura.

Comment: Ok pessoal, vou seguir a orientação dos dois então, acabei escolhendo a solução do @LeandroAngelo por parecer mais fácil de implementar pois não preciso criar outra classe e etc... mas entendendo melhor a forma correta e reutilizável realmente é a do LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o método **ContainsKey**, no qual você passa a **key** que está procurando e será retornado se ela existe ou não na sua coleção **Dictionary**.

```
string idFormaPgto = "1";

//Se a key existir no seu Dictionary nós iremos pegar o valor, senão iremos manter o valor 1
if (Dictionaries.ContainsKey[_order.FK_PEDIDOS_FORMA_PAGAMENTO])
      idFormaPgto = Dictionaries[_order.FK_PEDIDOS_FORMA_PAGAMENTO];
```

Caso queira fazer com uma condição ternária seria da seguinte forma:

```
    string idFormaPgto = Dictionaries.ContainsKey[_order.FK_PEDIDOS_FORMA_PAGAMENTO] ? Dictionaries[_order.FK_PEDIDOS_FORMA_PAGAMENTO] : "1";
```

Comment: Pedro, a principio gostaria de uma solução sem blocos para não poluir demais o código dentro do try catch principal, mas de qualquer forma vou testar.

Comment: usa um operador Ternário

Comment: Então use de forma ternária: idFormaPgto = Dictionaries.FormaPgto.ContainsKey(_order.FK_PEDIDOS_FORMA_PAGAMENTO) ? Dictionaries.FormaPgto[_order.FK_PEDIDOS_FORMA_PAGAMENTO] : "1";

Comment: Você pode inclusive criar uma extensão para ser reutilizável