# Como o compilador sabe que a classe x é uma extensão?

Tags: c#, classes, método

Nesse exemplo, crio um método de extensão da classe `DateTime` no c#:

```
static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public DateTime PrimeiroDiaDoMes(this DateTime data)
    {
        return new DateTime(data.Year, data.Month, 1);
    }

    public DateTime UltimoDiaDoMes(this DateTime data)
    {
        return new DateTime(data.Year, data.Month, DateTime.DaysI.......);
    }

    public bool EhFimDeSemana(this DateTime data)
    {
        return data.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday
            || data.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday;
    }
}
```

A questão é, como o compilador sabe que essa é uma classe de extensão, estou em duvida entre o nome da classe(Nome da classe base + Extension) ou o `this DateTime data`?

Comment: o operador `this` que faz esse trabalho. https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods

Comment: relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/136913/para-que-usar-m%C3%A9todos-de-extens%C3%A3o-do-c

Comment: faltou no exemplo o `static` também nos métodos

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O compilador não precisa saber que a classe é de extensão, nada exige isso, e na verdade não existe classe de extensão (ainda), existem classes estáticas que possuem métodos estáticos que são de extensão. Um dos motivos de se recomendar que escreva alguma coisa no nome para indicar que a classe tem o propósito de estender outra(s) classe(s). Inclusive a classe estática não precisa só ter métodos de extensão. O nome indica nada, inclusive eu só uso `Ext` no final do nome porque é suficiente pra eu pra identificar que é sobre isso.

O método de extensão é definido (até a versão atual que escrevo isso) por uma palavra chave `this` que vai antes do primeiro parâmetro declarado. Basta esta diferença sintática para o compilador saber.

[No futuro deve ter uma outra forma de expressar extensões diversas](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/164), não só métodos, e poderá ser por uma sintaxe que demonstre isso de forma mais clara e terá algo parecido com classe de extensão, mas não uma classe. Classes são sobrevalorizadas.

A própria classe estática é algo meio esquisito. C# tentou copiar um pouco a ideia do Java que estava na moda e que vendia a ideia que tudo deveria estar em classes, afinal naquela época só fazia sucesso a tecnologia que se vendia como orientada a objeto, aí começou uma obsessão por isso que não terminou ainda e estraga a cabeça de muitas pessoas, e faz códigos horríveis serem escritos para parecer que são OOP, mesmo quando o ideal é que não fossem. Agora já estão mais preparados para ter coisas que não são classes, porque nem sempre uma classe faz sentido. Chama de módulo ou outra coisa, não precisa inventar algo que não é uma classe só para fazer de conta que é OOP. Na verdade, o problema é até maior, foi o que deu pra resumir em um parágrafo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: @Maneiro passaram alguns dias, mas mesmo assim pergunto aqui: na sua resposta, " porque nem sempre uma classe faz sentido". Poderia me dar um exemplo? Obrigado!

Comment: @LuizAugusto isto depende de muita informação pra fazer em um comentário e está completamente fora do assunto da pergunta, mas ter classes estáticas é uma amostra disto, pra que chamar algo de classe se nem é uma classe?